# I have a npy file with multiple arrays that I would like to add to a column in a dataframe - python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, merge

My npy file contains 120951 arrays and is loaded as follows:

```
import numpy as np
arm = np.load('full_numpy_bitmap_arm.npy')
```

A
I also have a dataframe `df` that has 120951 rows and 6 columns. I would like to append each array in my "arm" variable to each row in my dataframe as a new column at the end of my dataframe. For example arm[0] would be in the first row last column and arm[1] in the second row last column, etc. I am not sure if the join function would work here because `arm` is not a dataframe. I was wondering if there is another way to do this? Thanks

Comment: What is `arm` shape and dtype?  Is it 1d object dtype or 2d numeric dtype (12095,?) shape?  Keep in mind that if you try to put one row in each cell of a dataframe column, you are breaking it up into 12095 arrays, and potentially loose a lot computational power.  And don't try to save the dataframe to a csv!

Comment: ```type(arm)``` is ```<class 'numpy.ndarray'>``` and ```arm.shape``` is ```(120951, 784)```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use pandas Concat method or one thing that i really like to do is map the dataframe to a dictionary along with the row or column i want to append and then just use pd.DataFrame over the dictionary